# Prove the following permutation mapping is a homomorphism.

Tags: permutations, group-homomorphism

Prove that $\varphi: S_n \to S_{n+1 }$, where for $\sigma\in S_{n}$: \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & \dots & n \\ 1\sigma & 2\sigma & \dots & n\sigma\\ \end{pmatrix}

$\varphi(\sigma)\in S_{n+1}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & \dots & n & n+1 \\ 1\sigma & 2\sigma & \dots & n\sigma & (n+1)\sigma \\ \end{pmatrix} $
is a homomorphism.

Wondering if anyone can explain how to prove this. Thanks.

---

[*From the comments:*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057799/prove-the-following-permutation-mapping-is-a-homomorphism#comment6304585_3057799)

> I literally have no idea where to start, hence why I haven't given details of where ive got stuck as I have no idea what methods I should use to even start it. I have done a few questions similar using matrices, trigonometric functions and other functions and found them fine. I have been using the standard definition for homomorphism that is that φ(ab)=φ(a)φ(b). However, with this question this did not seem to get me very far at all and I was wondering if there was something more clever or a silly detail I was overlooking.

Comment: How have you proved this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE @FinnJohnson. Your question may attract some negative votes. I let you here why it can be like that:

"This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc."

Comment: If you want answers, at the very least don't post questions as if you were instructing us to do what you want.

Comment: You prove it by showing that it has the properties of a homomorphism. How is a group homomorphism defined in your textbook/notes?

Comment: I literally have no idea where to start, hence why I haven't given details of where ive got stuck as I have no idea what methods I should use to even start it. I have done a few questions similar using matrices, trigonometric functions and other functions and found them fine. I have been using the standard definition for homomorphism that is that φ(ab)=φ(a)φ(b). However, with this question this did not seem to get me very far at all and I was wondering if there was something more clever or a silly detail I was overlooking.

Comment: The difficulty we have is that for anyone who has understood what is going on here the answer is essentially trivial, so it is hard to know what is tripping you up. How familiar are you with the symmetric groups? And why is it difficult to apply the definition you have of a homomorphism?

Comment: I have struggled with this one more as I tried to answer using two general permutations a,b from the symmetric group Sn. I made these the same form that σ takes in the question, and then attempted to apply φ directly to find φ(ab) and φ(a)φ(b) which would verify the definition of a homomorphism. However, this seems the wrong way to do it or much more difficult than previous questions I have encountered. It does make sense that this would work as a homomorphism, it's just I am struggling to find a way to word/ properly prove this.

Comment: the main difficult I am having is how to multiply the permutations together. Whether that be ab or φ(a)φ(b). I don't really know how you multiple such general permutations.

Comment: Well multiplying permutations is a standard operation in a symmetric group. Maybe start with doing some computations by hand with $n=3$ and $n=4$ - just choose two permutations and see what happens in the original group and then after you have applied the map. You are probably overthinking this, which essentially says you can find a copy of the symmetric group on $n$ items inside the symmetric group on $n+1$ items by choosing permutations which fix one of the items.

Comment: I think you have a typo. In the definition of $\varphi$, there's no such thing as $(n+1)\sigma$, since $\sigma\in S_n$. It would make the most sense for that to simply be $n+1$.